# 'Next Monday' or 'on next Monday'?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any preposition before "next week"? Is it "I would send you the proposal next Monday", or "...on next Monday"?

Comment: *Next* is a bit of a slippery word. I suppose it's functioning as an adjective here, but it can be an adverb *(to come next)*, and sometimes it's a preposition itself. So I don't think we'd want to add a *second* preposition, given that in speech many people wouldn't actually bother with either. *"I'll do it Monday"*.

Comment: I would be surprised to hear *I'll do it Monday* on this side of the Atlantic. @FumbleFingers.

Comment: @TRiG: Your profile doesn't give location, but presumably it's Eire, so geographically if not linguistically we're on the same side. I'm surprised [do it Monday](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+it+Monday&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) sounds odd to you - even though it's more a spoken form, that's plenty of occurences committed to print.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes. Ireland. Midlands. Somehow, the phrasing with no preposition sounds American to me. Perhaps I'm wrong. It's been known to happen before.

Comment: @TRiG: I can't say it seems particularly American to me. *Do it Monday* doesn't occur often enough to contrast any US/UK difference in NGram, but [come {on} Monday](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+Monday%2Ccome+on+Monday&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) is more common, and I see no evidence that Brits are any less likely than Americans to drop **"on"** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I'm probably wrong. It's just an impression I had.

Comment: How about *on Monday next week*?

Answer (score 9):

If you're asking the specific question regarding the preposition 'on', as to whether '*on next Monday*' is valid, then I would say no it isn't, you would never say '*on next Monday*'. You would always say '*I will send you the proposal **next Monday***'. Alternatively you could say '*I will send you the proposal **on Monday***'.

Otherwise the question is quite open-ended as usage would vary depending on the preposition in question. Taking the preposition 'for', you could say something like '*Will you be ready **next week**?*' and it would be valid to add the preposition as in '*Are you ready **for next week***'.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something *on Monday* or *next Monday* or *every Monday.*

Comment: Is there a difference? Can we use the same way in other contexts? And, can we not *do sth. Monday*? Any why's or why-nots?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good reference here

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm

You don't use 'on' when there is a 'next'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the question, the answer is no. There is no preposition with next/last: "next Monday", "next week". For reference one can look at this [page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/954_gramchallenge16/).

Answer (score -3):

We cant use more than one prepositions at same time. then it is better to use no Monday or next Monday in a sentence.

Comment: Hello, suresh. 'Next' must be classed as a determiner (sequencing) here, if it must be classed at all. It's better to treat 'next Monday' etc as being a fixed multi-word temporal adverbial. Though 'Monday next' is a legitimate variant.