# Can we say "Albert’s birthday is on next Saturday"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we say "Albert’s birthday is on next Saturday"? and "The concert was on last Saturday"? Does the preposition *on* in the two sentences have to be left out, or is it optional?

I know we should say "I will send you the proposal next Monday",in which "next Monday" is used as an adverbial modifying the verb *send*. But in my question, the sentence is "Albert’s birthday is on next Saturday?", in which *on next Saturday* is a complement after *be*. Is *on next Saturday* acceptable here, or still unacceptable just like when it is used as an adverbial?

Answer (score 0):

You could say that his birthday falls on a Saturday.

You could also say ALbert's birthday is next Saturday.

It would be incorrect to say "on next Monday."

BTW, this question is a repeat of: ['Next Monday' or 'on next Monday'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50283/next-monday-or-on-next-monday)

Comment: Is " on next Saturday " incorrect no matter whether it is used as an adverbial or a complement after "be"?