# The rationale behind "She is coming back next Wednesday" without "on"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

I have seen posts on this forum about how *She is coming back next Wednesday.* shouldn't have the preposition *on* before next Wednesday. What I want to know is whether anyone here can help provide the rationale behind this grammar rule? I would like to teach my ESL students in our next class about not having to use *on* before all of this Wednesday, that Wednesday, every Wednesday, last Wednesday etc., and I'd like to provide them an explanation instead of asking them to memorize it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to an adverbial/preposition phrase such as "on Monday" when you remove the proposition "on"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478034/what-happens-to-an-adverbial-preposition-phrase-such-as-on-monday-when-you-rem)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your suggestion, yet it doesn't answer my question. The other posts talks about "Monday vs on Monday" while mine "on next Wednesday vs next Wednesday".

Comment: @fluffy, at [](), gives the rule: 'In the examples you have given, it is fine to use a preposition. There are cases when prepositions must be omitted and when omission is optional:

prepositions of time are omitted before the words: last, next, this, that, some, every (We met last month. We meet every day.)'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Like I've mentioned I know we need it omitted, but I'd like to know the grammar rule that governs it, instead of just learning that we have to omit it. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly a duplicate of ['next Monday', or 'on next Monday'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50283/next-monday-or-on-next-monday/50285#50285). The 'grammar rule' is as stated above. The reason for the rule? I'd say it's just the way the language has evolved. FumbleFingers offers a guess, that 'on' and 'next' partially fulfil an equivalent grammatical role, and we tend to drop prepositions in temporal expressions where possible ('I'll see you Monday').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am not too sure about why there is a urgent need that my question be regarded as duplicated when it clearly is not, and be closed, especially when it hasn't been answered. When I mean by learning a rule that governs is, I am hoping to hear of the answer of something like "because xxx is the xxx so we don't need a preposition" or something along that line. Your way to explain it has been heard, and it would be deeply appreciated if we could together leave this question to see if other experts in the language might be able to provide us with a way to really explain it. Thanks.

Comment: @MissJoey: I don't know what kind of rule you are looking for. The rule that Edwin quotes above **is** the grammar rule that governs this.

Comment: The _fluffy_ excerpt mentioned above is missing a link; it is [Is it common to omit a preposition (in / on / of) before the month year week?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/is-it-common-to-omit-a-preposition-in-on-of-before-the-month-year-week/111232#111232). It is from the prestigious 'A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language' (Quirk et al); the reason behind the rule (and note that you ask for the rule, not the rationale, which is probably intractable ... unless someone finds a published article) is not mentioned. The quote contains a lot more rules to learn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it common to omit a preposition (in / on / of) before “the month (year / week /day) when they are used adjectively and adverbially?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/is-it-common-to-omit-a-preposition-in-on-of-before-the-month-year-week)

Answer (score 1):

It is a reasonable desire to find the rationale behind a grammatical rule.
It's what linguists want to do. It's what teachers and students would like to know.

Unfortunately, there are problems. One is that many rules don't have a rationale. They just are.
Also, they are very rarely stated specifically. 
Even when they are, they're quite often wrong.

In this specific case, there can't be a hard rule, because dropping *on* with these phrases is an ***optional*** phenomenon. That is, the speaker may do it, or may not, at their sole discretion, depending on how they're feeling at the moment. Nobody can tell them whether to use it or not.

It is always allowed to use *on* with dates. As noted, determiners like *next, last, this, that, some, every* can precede the dates after *on*, and the *on* may be omitted. This is also true of any noun phrase that refers to a specific date:

- *He returned home (on) the same day she left.*
- *I'm supposed to meet him (on) some day next month.*

But it doesn't work with **indefinite** noun phrases denoting dates:

- *I like  to run a on day like this.*
- **I like to run a day like this.* (asterisk means ungrammatical)

As for the rationale, it's like a lot of deletions of small words in English.
Complementizer *that*, infinitive *to*, *wh+be* in [Whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299),  [Conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), and so on. These are all meaningless words that guide the listener to the structures. As such, they are predictable.

When they're talking fast, with somebody they know well, people tend to leave things out. Every preposition in English is an unstressed syllable. English is a stress-timed language, in which unstressed syllables are reduced and jammed into the time between stressed syllables. So English speakers tend to delete predictable, unnecessary, unstressed syllables. A lot of these are prepositions. That's all, really.

Comment: This answer asserts that "on next Monday" is correct idiomatic standard English. [Other answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50283/next-monday-or-on-next-monday) and [a reference](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm) contradict this. I agree there are time constructions in which "on" is optional, but is this one of them?

Comment: It occurs to me you might think the other answers and the reference are all wrong. Which they might be. But I don't remember hearing or reading "on next Monday" in American or British English (though I think I recall hearing quaint expressions such as "on Monday next").

Comment: _She's coming back on next Monday, not next Tuesday._ I express no opinion of the reference or other answers. The point is that individual use of optional rules varies widely, to the point where one simply cannot say that any such sentence is or is not "correct idiomatic standard English", even if that phrase were not a contradiction in terms. Optional rules are **optional**, and just about every rule is optional under some situations.

Comment: The word "on" still seems out of place in that example. The world won't come to an end due to a stray preposition like that, and the main purpose of language, which is communication, is satisfied. In that sense spelling, punctuation, and so forth also are optional up to the point where communication fails. It still seems useful to me to recommend to ESL students that they say, "She's coming back next Monday, not next Tuesday."

Comment: Spelling and punctuation are optional in any case; they're not part of language or grammar. Orthography (written language) is technology and is no more relevant to sentence construction than are manual auto transmissions.